# dynamoDb - add new item if no similar items already added to the table

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Using DynamoDBMapper of dynamoDb I need to do the following:
1. Check if a Follower with a known leaderId and userId was already added to the Follower table.
2. If such follower was found - change it's state to "ACTIVE"
3. If such follower was not found - store a new Follower with given leaderId/followerId and state "ACTIVE"

State of follower will be used throughout the application as we use state to manage the workflow 
(we try not to delete any data in the database).

The simplified "Follower" class:

```
public class Follower {

@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
private String id;

    private String leaderId;
    private String followerId;
    private String state;
}
```

My current solution is
    1. use DynamoDBMapper to load list of Follower-s who meet the given leaderID/followerId parameters
    2. if no results - we generate a new Follower, otherwise we update the state of existing one

However I hope a more elegant "in one DynamoDBMapper call" solution exists.

```
public void follow(String leaderId, String followerId) {
    Follower follower = findFollower(leaderId, followerId);

    if(follower == null){
        follower = new Follower();
        follower.setLeaderId(leaderId);
        follower.setFollowerId(followerId);
    } else {
        follower.getBase().setState("ACTIVE");
    }

    getDbMapper().save(follower);
}
```

Comment: You could use leaderId-followerId as compound key and simply write the entity without checking whether it exists. This can sometimes work when one of the existing [`SaveBehavior`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.html)s fits your usecase (but you loose optimistic locking through versioning because you can't expect & increment a version without knowing it)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES`.

I had the same problem previously. I could solve it using below function.

```
/**
     * It's either save or update if the record is exist using param Follower data
     *
     * @param Follower object of the follower data
     */
    private static void saveOrUpdateAccountOperation(Follower  followerData) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClient amazonDynamoDBClient;
        if (CognitoSyncClientManager.getInstance().isUserLogin()) {
            amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(CognitoSyncClientManager.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider());
        } else {
            amazonDynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(AWSMobileClient.defaultMobileClient().getIdentityManager().getCredentialsProvider());
        }
        // UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES is similar to UPDATE, except that it ignores any null value attribute(s) and will NOT remove them from that item in DynamoDB.
        DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient,
                new DynamoDBMapperConfig(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES));
        // create or update the existing record
        dynamoDBMapper.save(followerData);
    }
```

You just pass your Follower object to this function it will take care your all three condition.

1. If you Follower object leaderId and userId not present then it will create it and added all other attributes with a default value.
2. If given followers would found then make sure your Followers class state attributes content the value "ACTIVE" it will only update on that attributes only.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem in my case was I could not explain DynamoDBMapper.save - which line to update as I did not know primary key at the moment of save-ing/update-in the item. I have solved it by eliminating "id" field and creating a composite key out of "followerId" and "leaderID" as per @zapl suggestion.